# SQL server: smoothed average of day of year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a subquery with avg reservoir inflow pr day of year (from 1-365). Now I would like to calculate a smoothed/moving average for each day of year in a new column.

Example: for january 1st (DayOfYear = 1) I would like to calculate a smoothed average of 21 days (10 pre and 10 post days). I.e an avg of days ranging from (356-11).  For day of year 55 the avg should be calculated on days of the year ranging from (45-65).

Her is the unfinished query based on a subquery called 'sub' where the 10 years of inflow first are averaged on day of year;

```
DECLARE  @Dager  int ;  
SET  @Dager  =  10; /* # days pre and post the actual day of year to be included in avg */

Select sub.Magasin, sub.DayOfYear, AVG(sub.Inflow) as AvgInflow 

FROM (SELECT Date, Magasin, Datepart(dy,Date) as DayOfYear, Value as Inflow
        FROM inputtable 
        WHERE Date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2008,1,1) and Date <= DATEFROMPARTS(2017,12,31)) sub

GROUP By sub.Magasin, sub.DayOfYear
ORDER BY sub.magasin, sub.DayOfYear
```

Comment: question is unclear, please try to add some sample data and expected output

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQl Server 2017

Comment: That date range will be zero days.  Why do you need a sub-query there?

Answer (score 3):

Without any sample data, I'm going to suggest this for SQL Server 2012+

(Your SQL looks like SQL Server 2012+)

```
SELECT
    Magasin, 
    Datepart(dy,Date) AS DayOfYear, 
    AVG(Inflow) OVER (
        PARTITION BY Magasin 
        ORDER BY YEAR(Date), Datepart(dy,Date)
        ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING  AND 10 FOLLOWING)
FROM
    inputtable
WHERE 
    Date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2008,1,1) and Date <= DATEFROMPARTS(2017,12,31))
```

Comment: I get an error when using partition by (incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'). Also I'm in doubt if this will work wrt to the fact that the smoothened average are "circular" (i.e....364,365,1,2,3,...).

Comment: I removed a comma which fixes the syntax. The circular can be fixed by changing `ORDER BY YEAR(Date), Datepart(dy,Date)` to `ORDER BY Datepart(dy,Date)`